# How to perform dynamic whereField in FireStore queries?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dynamic search fields where users can enter up to 7 fields within each text field.
[image]

According to firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), I can perform multiple queries as long as they are equality search. Is it possible to have a dynamic whereFields which increases based on the number of text fields searched. Each of these text fields represent a key in my Firestore that I can search equality for. I was able to store key pair values based on search text fields typed.

Here's how I implemented a search query based on a static query. How can I write this line of code to support multiple fields based on the dictionary?

```
func fetchFavoriteCards(userId: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[CardData], Error>) -> Void) {
        database.collection(FirebaseDatabaseKeys.cards)
            .whereField("isFavorite", isEqualTo: true)
            .whereField("owner", isEqualTo: userId)
            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let error = err {
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
            } else {
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No Cards")
                    return
                }

                let cards = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> CardData? in

                    do {
                        if let card = try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: CardData.self) {
                            return card
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("FirebaseManager fetchFavoriteCards", error.localizedDescription)
                        return nil
                    }
                    return nil
                }
                completionHandler(.success(cards))
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this function below to first search for the very first key in the dictionary, then filter using high order functions to filter per property but I'm not sure this is the best route to move forward, I'm not sure if Swift also supports accessing dot notation based on string.

```
func fetchCardsWithSearchParameters(parameters: [String: Any], completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[CardData], Error>) -> Void) {

    guard parameters.count > 0,
          let initialKeyValue = parameters.first else {
        //completionHandler(.failure(SearchParameterError.emptyParameters))
        return
    }

    database.collection(FirebaseDatabaseKeys.cards)
        .whereField(initialKeyValue.key, isEqualTo: initialKeyValue.value)
        .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let error = err {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
        } else {
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No Cards")
                return
            }

            let cards = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> CardData? in

                do {
                    if let card = try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: CardData.self) {
                        return card
                    }
                } catch {
                    return nil
                }
                return nil
            }
            // filter based on the rest of the parameters
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                cards.filter { $0.key == value }
            }


            completionHandler(.success(cards))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer provided by @bsod may be the answer but I am not sure the question is very clear. Are you asking how to query on multiple fields within a document? Did you see the Firebase Documentation [Query limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)? Is this an AND query or and OR query? Can you include a screen shot of what your Firestore data looks like so we can see how it's organized?

Comment: I did read the limitations and fortunately I only have about 7 properties to check equalities for. I'm not sure how Firestore data screenshot would help since it will be a replicate of the screenshot converted to camel-case to follow naming conventions. @bsod provided the requirements I needed to fill in multiple where clauses as each search text field is filled in to perform specific queries.

Comment: The question is/was unclear as we don't know if you are performing an AND query or an OR query. The issue with the answer is it's going to return an entirely different set of data for each query and you will have a lot of duplicate data, driving costs up. For example, is you query Sport: Baseball and then Year: 1985, the first query will return all Baseball matches, and the second query will return all 1985 matches and a lot of that will be duplicate data. If you are actually looking for all matches of Baseball in 1985 (an AND query), that's not going to do it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is construct a query object and append it through a loop that iterates through the parameters dictionary. This function, as an example, returns an optional `Query`:

```
func getQuery(from parameters: [String: Any]) -> Query? {
    var q: Query?
    
    for (n, p) in parameters.enumerated() {
        if n == 0 {
            /* This is the first iteration of the loop
             and so this is where we initialize the
             query object using the first parameter. */
            q = Firestore.firestore().collection(FirebaseDatabaseKeys.cards).whereField(p.key, isEqualTo: p.value)
        } else {
            /* This is an additional iteration of the loop
             and so this is where we append the existing
             query object with the additional parameter. */
            q = q?.whereField(p.key, isEqualTo: p.value)
        }
    }
    
    return q
}

if let query = getQuery(from: someParameters) {
    query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        ...
    }
}
```